Travel to Cuba to see family
My husband came to the US from Cuba in 1962.  He is a US citizen.  What does he need to do to travel to Cuba to see family?

We expect that participants here attempt to answer their own questions, and explain what they've done to do that. How have you tried to answer your own question?

IDK for sure but if he has dual Cuban / US citizenship I think he may need a Cuban passport. You can check travel document requirements by entering his personal details and proposed travel itinerary in the IATA website
